# The search box in mobile version of the site is too small and hidden

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design, mobile-web

When we access the Stackoverflow by the smartphone, even if it is a Galaxy Note 2, you have to touch a tiny down arrow to see the notification bar, and there is a little field for searching questions.

Shouldn't it be improved to the from with a bigger field, as it is an important functionality on the site?

[image]

Comment: Finger size plays a role here ;)

Comment: I guess it does not affect someone who just want to ask a question. But to someone who wants to read his inbox or wants to search for content, it's important.

Answer (score 1):

> Disclosure: I'm on a Galaxy S4 - smaller screen than the Note 2

I definitely know the feeling of browsing a "mobile optimized" site and still feeling like I have to use a toothpick to successfully "click" on certain UI elements... That said, **I really did not get this feeling when browsing the SE network on my phone**. The only thing I found annoying is trying to click on my username inside that top dropdown menu to get to my profile.

Lets be honest here for a second - you don't *really* have to click on that little arrow to trigger the dropdown, do you? Anywhere on the box containing the arrow works as well... Or is it that human fingers just touch the whole box in any case... not sure if this is the case on your 60m<sup>2</sup> screen - but I'm pretty sure the average person's finger will still cover the entire square.

---

I actually almost never click there in anycase (I'm just saying)... I have a bookmark to my profile page and just navigate from there...

Comment: The potential for mis-tap is much higher on sites like GIS, where the title (which is a link) extends all the way to the box with the arrow. That aside, it's not immediately obvious you have to expand that section to find the search bar either.

Comment: @tim - could you linkify `GIS` - I'm not sure what site you are referring to...

Comment: Sure, [Geographic Information Systems](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)